# while python calls re.findall, it hangs

Tags: python, regex, findall

The pattern I used is to fetch the latitude,longitude,url and so on:

```
pattern = "<article.*?latitude="(.*?)".*?longitude="(.*?)">.*?<a href="(.*?)".*?<figcaption.*?>(.*?)</figcaption>.*?</a>.*?<dt class="listing-type zsg-content_collapsed"><span.*?></span>(.*?)</dt>"
```

Sometimes it runs well, but sometimes it hangs in 
`re.findall(pattern, page)`.

The snippet code is:

```
def getPage(strUrl):
    socket.setdefaulttimeout(60)
    try:
        request =  urllib2.Request(strUrl)
        #mock browser 
        request.add_header("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0")
        response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
    except urllib2.URLError, e:
        print "Bad Url or timeout"
        print type(e)
        print e
        page = ''
    except socket.timeout,e:
        print "socket timeout"
        print type(e)
        print e
        page = ''
    else:
        page = response.read().decode('utf8')
        print "Get page contents successfully"
    return  m_page

def getHouseInfo(self,strRegularExpr,page):
    if strRegularExpr=='' or page=='':
        print "regular expression is null or page is null."
        return False

    pattern = re.compile(strRegularExpr,re.S)
    items = re.findall(pattern,page)
    return items

def getHomeDetailLinks(page):
    print "<<<<<<Get links starts>>>>>>"
    items = getHouseInfo(mapRe['homeDetailLinks'],page)
    print items
    print "<<<<<<Get links ends>>>>>>"
    return items

page =  getPage("http://www.zillow.com/homes/for_rent/02138_rb/1_p")
temp = getHomeDetailLinks(page)
print temp
```

While it hangs, I have to use CTRL+C to stop it, it throws blow exception:

```
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  ...
    items = self.getHouseInfo(mapRe['homeDetailLinks'],page)
  File ".../crawlbase.py", line 59, in getHouseInfo
    items = re.findall(pattern,page)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 177, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Could anyone give me some clue to fix this issue?

Comment: I dont now why it display as ".??)".?(.?).?.?(.*?)" while I type: pattern='<article.*?latitude="(.*?)".*?longitude="(.*?)">.*?<a href="(.*?)".*?<figcaption.*?>(.*?)</figcaption>.*?</a>.*?<dt class="listing-type zsg-content_collapsed"><span.*?></span>(.*?)</dt>'

Comment: Why aren't you using a html/xml parser? Tags are quite hard to parse with regex. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: The pattern in your question is invalid syntax... Use single quotes to enclose the string.

Comment: Side note: it doesn't make sense to compile your expressions just before using them. You should compile them only once (that is, your `mapRe` should contain compiled expressions, not strings).

Comment: First hint: use BeautifulSoup to get what you want. Second hint: if you post the whole HTML fragment showing what you want to extract from it, we could even answer your question.

Comment: I fixed my problem by using BeautifulSoup like soup = BeautifulSoup(page)  ;article = str(soup.findAll('div', id="search-results")); items = self.getHouseInfo(mapRe['homeDetailLinks'],article)